# Need (RPC + C# .Net + Framework 4.0) Samples

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, rpc

I want some samples in Remote Procedure Call in C#.Net and Framework 4.0. I had searched google a lot. But i dint find Step by Step Procedure of RPC Concept.

Kindly post some tutorials (RPC + C# .Net + Framework 4.0)

Comment: Do you mean classic .NET Remoting?

Comment: just google rpc c# and hit the first link... it explaines it pretty good

Comment: RPC is a very broad term and there are loads of different ways to achieve it. You can narrow down your question by telling if you want to use a .NET only approach, what kind of clients you want to support (only your application, applications developed in java/c++ etc) and what kind of OSes (linux, windows etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is rather general - RPC can be everything these days (like SOAP, XML-RPC, "classic RPC", .NET remoting etc.).

For "classic RPC" see:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/rpcintro1.aspx
- http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Introduction-to-RPC-on-Windows-Part-I/
- http://netbula.com/oncrpc/
- http://www.distinct.com/products/rpc/rpc-dot-net.asp

For "XML-RPC" see:

- http://codinghints.blogspot.com/2010/03/xml-rpc-calls-with-c.html
- http://www.xml-rpc.net/

For general info and .NET specific see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324
- http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/b438/html/net.htm

Comment: Microsoft SDK's have many samples.

Comment: these links are all c++. The question says c#.